# Nutch topN selection criterion

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Does the topN threshold consider page score for the selection. If it's set to say 10, does Nutch queue up the 10 top scoring URLs on a page? Does this work through the webgraph or is it just the first 10 that it comes across on a page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. TopN considers page score.

Comment: Any idea how the scoring works on the first page that it downloads? Lets say it crawls XYZ.com and found 5 links on it. Since it doesn't have any data to do the OPIC scoring yet like the number of inlinks to each link, how does it queue them up?